# LESS: mixin with non-class ruleset

Tags: css, less

In LESS, I am trying to define the `button.c2` ruleset, to be applied to `<button class="c2">...</button>` elements. This ruleset is mainly based on the `button.c1` ruleset. However, the following code produces a ParseError:

```
button.c2 {
  button.c1;// Trying to import a ruleset
  ... // additional rules, such as font-size: 120%;
}
```

It seems to me that the ParseError is caused by the fact that the imported ruleset does not refer to a class or ID ("button.c1" does not start with a "." or a "#"). From the [LESS documentation](http://lesscss.org/#-variables):

> Any CSS class or id ruleset can be mixed-in that way.

Why is there such a limitation? Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limitation might just be ease of parsing, since `.` or `#` don't show up as the first character of a normal style rule the parser automatically knows that those should be mixed in.

You could get around it by defining `.c1` as a mixin and using it for both `button`s:

```
.c1() {
    // c1 rules
}

button.c1 {
    .c1;
}

button.c2 {
    .c1;
    // additional rules
}
```

However, coming up in LESS 1.4.0 are `:extend` selectors, which *will* allow you to do what you want. The syntax would be:

```
button.c2:extend(button.c1) {
    // additional rules
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I may not modify the definition the file that contains the button.c1 ruleset.

Comment: @RégisB. You're out of luck for now, I'm afraid. I've edited my post to include info about the upcoming LESS 1.4.0, which should solve your problem

Comment: Ok: not possible for now, but will be possible in the future. Fine with me!